# invoking multiple browser on selection

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

the problem is that i want to invoke IE,Firefox in my application and when i select one from the drop-down it should actually take the latest from the machine and should run the application in it. can any one suggest how to code for it .i am using C#, selenium web-driver to build

Comment: Latest what? The browser? What do you mean?
What ever is set as default browser is launched by the application if you use Process.Start("html link");

Comment: ZEN-WALKER , thanks for replying , yes i am talking about the latest installed browser, what if i don't want the default browser and want to use the other browser on selection .how would you recommend to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Starts Firefox in the google page.

And:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", "http://www.google.com/");
```

in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Use Process.Start() API for starting the required browser. How ever, you may need to hardcode the values viz firefox, ie, chrome, etc. Which is kinda problem.

So, you can find all the installed browsers from the registry at this path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet

Hope it helps :)